# How to iterate through the values of a column without using for loop?

Tags: r

Using this command:

```
library(rgeolocate)
file <- system.file("extdata","GeoLite2-Country.mmdb", package = "rgeolocate")
results <- maxmind(c("94.69.228.169","54.36.149.33"), file, c("country_code", "country_name"))
```

How is it possible to change the `c("94.69.228.169","54.36.149.33")` with and iteration but not need the for loop?

Let's say this is a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("94.69.228.169","54.36.149.33"))
```

and want to use something like this

```
results <- maxmind(for(i in nrow(df)){df$id[i]}, file, c("country_code", "country_name"))
```

Comment: Please specify where you find `maxmind`. (I'm inferring `rgeolocate`, please be clear in your questions.)

Comment: Do you mean `maxmind(df$id, file, ...)`?

Comment: `maxmind(df$id, file, c("country_code", "country_name"))` works , right?